# Why do I get the value of the default method and not the overridden one?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-interface

```
interface MyInterface {
    default int someMethod() {
        return 0;
    }

    int anotherMethod();
}

class Test implements MyInterface {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test q = new Test();
        q.run();
    }

    @Override
    public int anotherMethod() {
        return 1;
    }
    
    void run() {
        MyInterface a = () -> someMethod();
        System.out.println(a.anotherMethod());
    }
}
```

The execution result will be 0, although I expected 1. I don't understand why the result of the overridden method is not returned, but the result of the default method is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becouse you used another implementation with lambda, where implementation of another method is "some method". You can create interfaces with lambda. On this case you do

`MyInterface a = new Test();  System.out.println(a.anotherMethod());`

or :

```
    MyInterface a = () -> 1;
    System.out.println(a.anotherMethod());
```

Answer (score 5):

The statement `MyInterface a = () -> someMethod();` is more or less equivalent to the following code:

```
MyInterface a = new MyInterface() {
  @Override int anotherMethod() {
    return someMethod();
  }
};
```

`someMethod()` is not overridden anywhere in your example, so the default implementation is used. The default implementation of `return 0`. So calling `a.anotherMethod()` is expected to return `0`.

The overridden `Test#anotherMethod` is never called by your code. If you want to execute this method, you must call `this.anotherMethod()` (or assign `MyInterface a = this;`).

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't call the overridden method.

```
MyInterface a = () -> someMethod();
System.out.println(a.anotherMethod());
```

`a` has nothing to do with the `Test` instance in which it is called.